# include paths in php.ini not updating - under a zend setup

Tags: zend-framework, php

I have been trying to update my include paths to include phpDocumentor, but regardless of what I put in my php.ini file, the phpInfo shows the same information.

Does anyone know where Zend takes its include paths from?

I had posted on troubles setting up PHPdocumentor (ongoing)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130630/phpdocumentor-cannot-open-php-doc-in-a-zend-setup

But the flow on issue that I cannot update my include paths in PHP.ini may be of interest to other Zend users, so I thought I would remove this secondary question into another post.

My include path in php.ini (windows) looks like this...

```
include_path = ".;c:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\includes;\c:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\lib;\C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\PEAR;\c:\zendServer\rental\public\phpDocumentor-2.0.0a10"
```

but PHP info on the Zend sever looks like this (local)...

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\GUI/library;C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\GUI/application\CE/models
```

AND (master)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library

I have tried restarting the server and computer to no effect, so it seems that Zend takes its include settings from somewhere else.  Has anyone come across this in the past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you've installed a PHP instance in `C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP`, and also a Zend Server in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer`.
The Zend Server is bundled with its own Apache and PHP versions.
The PHP.INI configuration file for the Zend Server should be located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\etc\php.ini`.
After changing the configuration file you must restart the Zend Server Apache instance to activate changes.
Maybe the simplest way to do this is from the Zend Server web administration console, which should be accessible (if you didn't specify a custom port for the web server during the installation process) by accessing the `http://localhost/ZendServer` url from the machine where the Zend Server resides.
The PHP.INI configuration of the Zend Server can also be modified from the web administration console.
Have a look at [this page](http://devzone.zend.com/1389/getting-started-with-zend-server-ce/) for further information on how to get started with Zend Server.

Comment: Enzino - great answer.  I have been sucessful in updating the include path using the ZendServer web console, so this does solve my issue.  Thanks so much.  On the old version of PHP it has been deleted so I need to remove from my path variable. I was working with the PHP.ini specified in the PHP info on the web console. So still confused why Zend ignores what is in the actual config file.

Comment: **One note**, if you edit the PHP.ini supplied by Zend Server by hand, the include_path is **not** set in the normal _Paths and Directories_ section. Instead it is way down in the _Zend_ section. If you use the normal include_path it will overridden by the one in the Zend section.

Comment: Thanks this is useful, so if I use this php.ini outside zend the normal include path would apply.

Comment: Enzino, have accepted now.  Sorry are still learning the overflow system and protocols ;-)